# Show that there is $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_0)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(x_k)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ continuous and $ \{x_k\}_{k=1}^n \subseteq [a,b] $  show that there is $x_0\in[a,b]$  such that  $$f(x_0)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(x_k) $$
How should I go about it?

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: What have you yourself tried to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, we have that there are $p,q\in[a,b]$, such that:
$$f(p)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\mbox{ and }f(q)=\min_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$$
So, for every $i=1,2,\dots,n$, we have:
$$f(q)\leq f(x_i)\leq f(p)$$
So, by adding all these equations for $i=1,2,\dots,n$, we have:
$$nf(q)\leq\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\leq nf(p)\Leftrightarrow f(q)\leq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\leq f(p)$$
Now, since $f$ is continuous, by the Intermediate Values Theorem - we assume that $f$ is not constant, since, in that case, the proof is trivial - we have that there exists a $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that:
$$f(x_0)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)$$
which is what has been requested.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(x_k)$.

Then 
$$g(x_1)+....+g(x_n)=0$$

Deduce from here that either $g(x_j)=0$ for all $j$ or $g(x)$ takes both positive and negative values. Use IVT.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=2$, this is simply the intermediate value theorem: if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in $[a,b]$, then there is some $x_0\in [x_1,x_2]$ such that $f(x_0)=\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}$.

With this as the base case, you can conclude the a similar result for $n$ points using induction.

Answer (score 0):

The mean of $f(x_k)$ is between $\min f(x_k)=f(x_m)$ and $\max f(x_k)=f(x_M)$ so by intermediate value theorem you can find $x_0$ in $[\min(x_m,x_M),\max(x_m,x_M)]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m,M$ be the minimum and maximum values of $f$ on $[a,b].$ Clearly

$$m\le \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\le M.$$

Since $f$ takes on every value in $[m,M]$ by the intermediate value theorem, we're done before we even get started.